# What good reasons are there for having the same namespace split across different assemblies?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, namespaces, .net-assembly

I tend to like collecting types within a namespace, within the same compiled assembly - it makes things easy to find and references easy to manage.

However, I have seen examples where the same namespace is split across projects and assemblies (in other words, in order to gain access to the complete namespace, you must reference multiple dlls).

Can anyone give me some good reasons why you might want to arrange code this way?

thanks

Comment: I have never seen this before.  It sounds like a terrible idea!  How would either namespace know that each other exists?  Can the namespaces be used exclusively?

Comment: This happens often.  For example, System.Web exists in multiple assemblies.  If one assembly isn't referenced, the classes in that assembly won't be accessible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231368/separate-projects-or-multiple-class-files-namespace-best-practice-in-c-sharp

Found this, gives some pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

I usually find myself doing this when I'm writing libraries which has some functionality requiring other assemblies.

For example, I just wrote some converters to convert .NET data types to SQL data types. Most of these I kept in my standard utilities library. The converter for `System.Drawing.PointF`, however, obviously requires `System.Drawing`. Rather than forcing all of my projects referencing my utilities namespace to reference `System.Drawing`, I pulled that part of my library into a separate assembly under the same namespace. Now if you need to convert `PointF` you can reference the additional assembly, and find the converter in the same namespace as all the others.

I actually asked this question over on [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/144472/30039).

Comment: Dan - the answer on the other question about deployable units makes more sense to me, but I still haven't seen a killer reason to do it. The kind of reason that makes me think 'yes, that's absolutely the right way'. It seems to be matters of preference...

Comment: @jimmy_terra You didn't ask for killer reasons, just good ones. It really is a matter of preference.